# Use search API to find items that begin with a specific letter

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, sharepoint-framework

I am Developing a SharePoint Extension web part for O365. The purpose of the web part is to allow the user to click on a letter of the alphabet and then through the search API return all the items with a title that begins with the selected letter.

I have figured out how to use the search API for finding keywords:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'
```

But I don't know how to use the API to get all items that begin with a certain letter. I have tried googling an answer for this but haven't found anything. Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use refinement filters or wild cards in SharePoint search API?

Maybe one of the endpoint given below:

```
_api/search/query?refinementfilters='Title:("micro*")'
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint 2013 REST Api - refinementfilters "Containts" OR "SubstrinOf" operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5eb4cd2e-2edf-4ac5-807d-a968f0996e61/sharepoint-2013-rest-api-refinementfilters-quotcontaintsquot-or-quotsubstrinofquot?)

Or

```
http://server/_api/search/query?query_parameter=value*
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint Search REST API overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)

Also, check this useful article on KQL, [Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference).

Comment: Thanks, for the references. I think will work for me.

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer, it will help others to find the best solution easily.